# ShellExecute ends up in error C2065 don't know how to fix

Tags: c++

I have a timer, after which a local html file should be executed, but I hit some kind of error:

```
int delay = 120;
delay *= CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

clock_t now = clock();

while (clock() - now < delay);

string strWebPage = "file:///D:/project/site/scam.html";

strWebPage = "file:///" + strWebPage;
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, NULL, strWebPage, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

return 0;
```

> E0413 no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "LPCWSTR" exists

I'm new to C++, so it might be an obvious solution.

Could anyone point me to how I can fix it?

Comment: Please don't post images.  That said, you want `ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, NULL, strWebPage.c_str (), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`.  And use `nullptr`, not `NULL`.  `NULL` is an anachronism.

Comment: You'll also want to switch `std::wstring` since `ShellExecute` takes a wide character string.

Comment: Why are you using *two* `file:///` prefixes?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The `ShellExecute()` function comes in two variants: `ShellExecuteA()` and `ShellExecuteW()`. Unless OP has `#define UNICODE` hiding somewhere, he is using the correct string type for that function. (Oh, but now I’ve looked at the image.)

Comment: @Dúthomhas it is clear from the error message that `UNICODE` is actually defined.  It doesn't have to be a `#define` in code, it can also be set via project settings instead (and likely is).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I admit I missed that the first time through, because I don’t like clicking on pictures. I addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have *two* problems.

But first, you should *always* take the time to read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea). For Win32 functions, you can get to a known function by typing something like “`msdn ShellExecute`” into your favorite search engine and clicking the “Lucky” button.

#### Problem One

`ShellExecute()` is a **C** function. It does not take `std::string` as argument. It needs a pointer to characters. Hence:

```
std::string filename = "birds.html";
INT_PTR ok = ShellExecute( 
    NULL,             // no window
    NULL,             // use default operation 
    filename.c_str(), // file to open
    NULL,             // no args to executable files
    NULL,             // no start directory
    SW_SHOWNORMAL );
if (ok <= 32)
  fooey();
```

Notice that we pass a `const char *` to the function as the file to <default verb>.

#### Problem Two

From your image it would appear that you have your application declared as a Unicode application. In other words, somewhere there is a `#define UNICODE`.

This makes `ShellExecute()` expect a WIDE character string (`const wchar_t *`)as argument, not a narrow string (`const char *`).

You can still use a narrow string by simply specifying that you want the narrow version:

```
INT_PTR ok = ShellExecuteA(
    ...
```

I recommend you look at how you set up your project to figure out how you got things to think you were using wide strings instead of narrow strings.